# Are type="module" javascript files all isolated from each other?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two external scripts referenced at the bottom of my HTML document:

```
<script type="module" src="/scripts-1.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/scripts-2.js"></script>
```

I have been running some tests and I can see that if I add:

```
const logHelloWorld = () => console.log('Hello World');

logHelloWorld();
```

to either external file then the function will execute.

But if I add the function declaration to `/scripts-1.js` and `logHelloWorld();` to `/scripts-2.js`, then the console shows the error:

> ReferenceError: `logHelloWorld` is not defined

Is that because all `type="module"` scripts are all isolated from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Resources to be used by other modules must be explicitly `export`ed, and `import`ed where they are needed.

[Here](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/introduction-to-es6-modules-49956f580da) is one of many guides to the ES6 module system.

Answer (score 2):

Modules are in fact "insulated" from each other. You can `export` things from one module and `import` them into another. Generally speaking, the `type="module"` flag is considered a futuristic feature that isn't used generally at the moment. It's better to use another tool to bundle all of your JS files together like webpack.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I wasn't aware that there was a _Bundling vs. Native Modules_ debate. I started using native ES2015 Modules at the start of 2019 and I *really* like what I have seen so far. Back in Jan 2019, I developed a PHP-based workaround to compensate for lack of support for `Dynamic Import`, but I see that support has now arrived: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import Articles like https://philipwalton.com/articles/using-native-javascript-modules-in-production-today/ from last month suggest that uptake of native modules may start to ramp up from now onwards.